# What DOS commands do I use to extract a tarball?

Tags: windows

A friend sent me a tarball entitled cst-web.tar.gz

I am on a work computer that doesn't allow me to download files so I thought to extract the tarball using the DOS commands. However, when I use any of the DOS commands I found such as

```
tar xf [filename]
# or
tar -xvzf [filename]
```

I get the message that the command is *'not recognizable as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'*.

Stuck on what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Windows that can extract a tarball.  You will need a third-party program like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/).  If you can't download files, you can't open the tarball.